Promise is never returned in firestore().collection('Users').add({ name: 'Ada Lovelace', age: 30 })
I'm using React Native with Expo and library @react-native-firebase/firestore.
I'm trying to add a document to a collection in Firestore but the promise never returns so nothing is inserted in firestore.
The promise that never resolves is this one:
// Attempt to add user
const result = await userRef.add({
  name: 'Ada Lovelace',
  age: 30,
});

I would expect the user object to get saved in Firestore and to see the following logs:
console.log('Result:', result);
This is my code:
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

// Configuración de Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain: "xxx",
  projectId: "xxx",
  storageBucket: "xxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxx",
  appId: "xxx",
  measurementId: "xxx"
};

// Inicializar Firebase
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  console.log('Initializing Firebase');
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} else {
  console.log('Firebase already initialized');
}

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Firestore instance:', firestore());
  }, []);

  const addUser = async () => {
    try {
      console.log('Adding user...');
      const userRef = firestore().collection('Users');
      console.log('User collection reference:', userRef);

      // Attempt to add user
      const result = await userRef.add({
        name: 'Ada Lovelace',
        age: 30,
      });

      console.log('Result:', result);
      console.log('User added!');
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.error('Error adding user: ', error);

      // Captura de errores HTTP
      if (error.response) {
        console.log('Error data:', error.response.data);
        console.log('Error status:', error.response.status);
        console.log('Error headers:', error.response.headers);
      } else if (error.request) {
        console.log('Error request:', error.request);
      } else {
        console.log('Error message:', error.message);
      }
      console.log('Error config:', error.config);

      alert(`Error adding user: ${error.message}`);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Add User to Firestore</Text>
      <Button title="Add User" onPress={addUser} />
    </View>
  );
}

and this is my rule:
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}

I'm using these versions:
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^20.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^20.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^20.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^20.3.0",


What actually happens here other than what you expect?  Is there an error?  What is it?  Please edit the question to include more debugging details.

Thanks Doug, I've edited my comment. Basically I would expect the object to get saved in Firestore and to see the logs console.log('Result:', result); which is after the promise that never gets resolved  const result = await userRef.add({
name: 'Ada Lovelace',
age: 30,
});

Right, so, what happens other than what you expect?  Are you saying this code does absolutely nothing at all?  Or is there an error?  Have you added logging to figure out what its actually doing?

This code reaches  console.log('User collection reference:', userRef);
correctly but when it reaches  const result = await userRef.add({         name: 'Ada Lovelace',         age: 30,       }); nothing happens, it stops. No more logs are printed, no user is persisted in Firestore, no errors are thrown in the logs. Nothing.
